# Why Return False When I Select Correct Answer in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why return false when I select correct answer in Jetpack Compose? I have question and answers. Question and answers are random elements. There are one question and 4 answers. When I select corrrect answer it returns false. I cannot figure out why this happening. How to solve this?

```
val characters = mutableListOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z")
var randomElement = characters.random()
var randomElement2 = characters.random()
var randomElement3 = characters.random()
var randomElement4 = characters.random()
var answers = mutableListOf(randomElement, randomElement2, randomElement3, randomElement4)
var shuffleAnswers = answers.shuffle()

@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    var answers by remember { mutableStateOf(answers) }
    var question by remember { mutableStateOf(randomElement) }
    var selectedIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(-1) }
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "Select: $question",
            fontSize = 36.sp,
        )
        LazyColumn(content = {
            items(answers.size) { index ->
                Button(
                    onClick = { selectedIndex = index },
                    colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                        backgroundColor = if (selectedIndex == index) {
                            Color.LightGray
                        } else {
                            Color.White
                        }
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .selectable(
                            selected = selectedIndex == index,
                            onClick = {}
                        ),
                ) {
                    Text(text = answers[index])
                }
            }
        })
        Button(onClick = {
            randomElement = characters.random()
            randomElement2 = characters.random()
            randomElement3 = characters.random()
            randomElement4 = characters.random()
            answers = mutableListOf(randomElement, randomElement2, randomElement3, randomElement4)
            answers.shuffle()
            question = randomElement
            if (selectedIndex in 0..3) {
                if (randomElement == answers[selectedIndex]) {
                    Log.d("myTag", "correct")
                    Log.d("myTag", answers[selectedIndex])
                    Log.d("myTag", randomElement)
                } else {
                    Log.d("myTag", "false")
                    Log.d("myTag", answers[selectedIndex])
                    Log.d("myTag", randomElement)
                }
            }
            selectedIndex = -1
        }) {
            Text(text = "Next")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you re-assign values to your variables at the `onClick`. If you only make the check on the `onClick` like below it works.

```
Button(onClick = {
        if (randomElement == answers[selectedIndex]) {
            Log.d("TAG", "correct $randomElement")
        }else {
            Log.d("TAG", "wrong $randomElement != ${answers[selectedIndex]}")
        }
        selectedIndex = -1
    }) {
        Text(text = "Next")
    }
```